# RSS item list in block with dates

Tags: 7, feeds

I need a module which can fetch rss titles + publish dates and show them in a block/teaser. I tried aggregator and it does some of the job, but you cannot show publish dates in the list. The "read more" link should go to the original RSS or custom URL. It is important that all links link to the original url in the RSS and not to any view in drupal. Any suggestions for modules or other solutions?

Comment: What do you mean by "you cannot show publish dates in the list"? As an rss always comes with the date usually called timestamp

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to display an RSS feed (rather that import the entries into your site's actual database and then show in a view), then I would use Feedburner, which will help you get the html code to publish any RSS feed.

- Get a [Feedburner account](http://feedburner.google.com)
- Create a new feed to manage, using the feed's URL on the front page screen
- Under the 'Publicize' tab, go to 'BuzzBoost' and activate that service at the bottom of the page
- Once it's activated, you can get the embed code.  Just paste that code into a brand new block, and place the block whereever you want!

[image]

p.s. Further down that same page (the Publicize -> BuzzBoost page, I just cut off my screenshot too early), you can customize the feeds settings, such as should you display a date, and if so in what format, and how many characters of the post teaser to display, etc.  Play around with them to get the feed listing you want!

Comment: The site I am working on is cloned out for many libraries and therefore most of the stuff should work "out of the box". I don't want to rely on all libraries setting up feedburner accounts. For easier management I am looking for something that works without additional external services.

Comment: Oh ok. Maybe someone else can chime in about how they'd work an RSS-style feed to show up attractively on the website without a Feedburner-like service. Just in case though, I wanted to mention that you can have a *single* Feedburner account and manage all of your RSS feeds through it. Otherwise, I certainly wouldn't want to have a bunch of them either.  :-)

Comment: I have made a new module called aggregator_blocklist. I just copied some stuff from aggregator and made the proper changes as I don't want to hack the drupal core. It's basically just the block_view, so I still use aggregator for the feed import.